# Is there a way to wait for the execution of a consumer in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

In MassTransit if you want to await the execution of a consumer so that you can get the response there is `IRequestClient<TCommand>` which has a method `GetResponse<TResponse>(Command)`. Is that the only way you can await the execution of a consumer in MassTransit?

What I want to be able to say is after publishing did the consumer execute successfully or did it error out if it errored out I want to be able to notify interested parties that the command errored out.

Comment: I've updated the title, feel free to rollback if it doesn't accurately describe your question. Although it seems to me that you don't care about running this synchronously, and that you only want to handle errors aka `Fault<>`s?

Answer (score 1):

It is the easiest way, yes. If you have a method that needs to publish/send a message and wait (via `await`, in this case) for a consumer to consume the message, using the request client creates a unique `RequestId` and specifies the response address so that the consumer can notify the requestor via a response.

If you're really more interested in knowing if there was an exception consuming the message, you can create a separate consumer that consumes `Fault<TCommand>`. If the consumer throws an exception, MassTransit will publish a fault message of this type which can then be consumed to deal with the exception.

> Note that if the request client is used, faults are only sent back to the response address and are not published.

Beyond those basic capabilities, sagas may also be used to orchestrate the original message, faults, etc. if so required.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question really appreciate the time and effort. I will definitely explore Fault<TCommand> but I think I'll explain a bit more about what I want to achieve. For example-: There is a simple user registration form that displays a success message when the user submits the registration form and the user is successfully registered but when the registration fails we get an error message saying the registration failed. 

** Cant fit my entire comment  I will add another one which is continuation of this **

Comment: So from a system standpoint, UserRegistration is an action so essentially is a command. When that request lands in the controller I would like to Send/Publish a command and get a notification or indication or response from the command-handler the execution is completed successfully because I have an error handling mechanism in the BaseController that will handle the error that occurred. I am adding a link to the repo if you want to have a look the code. Thanks a lot in advance for helping me.

https://github.com/Vibhav-Deo/Todo

Comment: would be able to please answer this as well? Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Oh I know what you want, and I've shown you a way to do it. There are many ways to manage user interaction via APIs, you just need to explore them on your own.